# Какая разница, когда делать json.dumps()?

Tags: python, json

Написал небольшой код на Python, который покупает биткоины на бирже OKX при помощи API. Для создания ордера необходимо передать подпись (она создается при помощи API-ключей, которые можно получить на сайте) в заголовки запроса. В [документации](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#overview-rest-authentication-signature) написано как подписать запрос. Также для создания подписи необходимо передать параметры для ордера в виде строки. Для преобразования словаря в строку я использую пакет `json`, но фишка в том, что если я сначала преобразую словарь в строку, то код будет работать исправно, но если преобразовать словарь в строку во время создания подписи, то получим ошибку `{"msg":"Invalid Sign","code":"50113"}`, я не силён во всех этих JSON`ах, но хотелось бы узнать почему так происходит.

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
from datetime import datetime

import requests

from config import APIs

api_public = APIs['OKX']['public']
api_private = APIs['OKX']['private']
passphrase = APIs['OKX']['passphrase']

base_url = 'https://www.okx.com'


# Тут ok
def func1():
    timestamp = str(datetime.now().utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z')
    body = json.dumps({
        'instId': 'BTC-USDT',
        'tdMode': 'cash',
        'side': 'buy',
        'ordType': 'market',
        'sz': '1'
    })  # Параметры ордера, делаём из dict`а str здесь

    message = timestamp + 'POST' + '/api/v5/trade/order' + body
    signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    )

    headers = {
        'OK-ACCESS-KEY': api_public,
        'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
        'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post('https://www.okx.com/api/v5/trade/order', headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.text)


# Тут не ok
def func2():
    timestamp = str(datetime.now().utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z')
    body = {
        'instId': 'BTC-USDT',
        'tdMode': 'cash',
        'side': 'buy',
        'ordType': 'market',
        'sz': '1'
    }  # Параметры ордера

    message = timestamp + 'POST' + '/api/v5/trade/order' + json.dumps(body)  # Делаем из dict`а str здесь
    signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    )

    headers = {
        'OK-ACCESS-KEY': api_public,
        'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
        'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post('https://www.okx.com/api/v5/trade/order', headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1()
    func2()
```

Comment: Никакой разницы. Главное - делать. А вот тут ``data=body`` во втором случае не делается.

Answer (score 1):

У вас во втором примере для переменной `response` не объявлен `body` как JSON.

Если хотите объявлять JSON потом, то:

```py
response = requests.post('https://www.okx.com/api/v5/trade/order', 
    headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать так как вы подсказали, но результат такой же: {"msg":"Invalid Sign","code":"50113"}